# angular controller bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to open a bootstrap modal with the below code in the service method which is invoked from a controller.

```
 openModal(type){

    this.$modal.open({
       animation: this.$rootScope.animationsEnabled,
       templateUrl: '../app/components/'+type+'/'+type+'.html',
       controller: DynamicController,
       controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
```

}

The modal is activated by clicking on the below links.

```
  <li><a href ng-click="openModal('signup','LoginController')">Sign In</a></li> {{test}}
  <li><a href ng-click="openModal('signup','SignupController')">Sign Up</a></li>
```

I want the modal to use the respective controller (in place of DynamicController) based on what link is clicked. Is there a better way to achieve this feature?

Comment: There might be a 'better' way, but I like what you've done (other than forgetting the DynamicController argument on openModal)

Answer (score 0):

The Angular UI bootstrap's modal allows passing a string in the controller Property. If you need more control over the passed value for the controller, I'd recommend this way:

```
openModal(type, controller){

  this.$modal.open({
     animation: this.$rootScope.animationsEnabled,
     templateUrl: '../app/components/'+type+'/'+type+'.html',
     controller: function(){
        return controller || 'DefaultController'
     },
     controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
```